# Can't push git updates & run Unix commands when connecting via SSH

Tags: java, linux, git, ssh, centos

I have installed java 8 on my bluehost VPS. I have followed http://tecadmin.net/install-java-8-on-centos-rhel-and-fedora/
instructions .

in order to add directories to `PATH` variable I have added

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45
JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre
```

to `etc/environment` file.

after that I can't push upgrades to my git repository and when I login via ssh I can't run unix command.

my server OS is **CentOS** and its **64bit**

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT :**

---

**Error shown in git :**

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags origin master:master
Pushing to root@162.144.42.157:/home/darmanjo/darmanjoo.git

bash: git-receive-pack: command not found

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**SSH Problem :**

```
login as: root
root@162.144.42.157's password:
Last login: Tue Apr 21 15:26:53 2015 from 109-110-182-162-dynamic.shabdiznet.com
-bash: id: command not found
-bash: tty: command not found
root@server.darmanjoo.com [~]# ls
-bash: ls: command not found
root@server.darmanjoo.com [~]#
```

also my `echo $PATH` shows :

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin:/root/bin
```

Comment: if you `echo $PATH` what do you see?  It sure seems like that is going to have the wrong value in it

Comment: @EricRenouf
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin:/root/bin

Comment: I think @etan-reisner is right then, the PATH variable did not expand correctly in the file you put it in, so you have $PATH in the middle of your PATH instead of /bin;/usr/bin; etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page is incorrect.

Those assignment lines are not valid in `/etc/environment`.

Variable expansion does not occur for lines in `/etc/environment`.

See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/664169/what-is-the-difference-betwen-etc-environment-and-etc-profile) for some more discussion about this.

Comment: What do you mean. where should I put these lines. can you make an example please?

Comment: JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45

Comment: JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre

Comment: PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/bin:/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin

Comment: For your user you put them in your user's shell startup scripts. For all users use the system shell startup scripts. `/etc/environment` is not forr that (not directly).

Comment: I can't edit /etc/environment. it says -bash: nano: command not found

Comment: You are going to need to use the full path. `/bin/nano` or `/usr/bin/nano` or whatever. Also CentOS 6+ has packages for openjdk 1.8.0 available by default so installing manually isn't necessary.

Comment: Sorry I'm bothering you Etan, but should I add these lines to my /etc/profil.d?

Comment: Let this also be a bit of a lesson about following "random" directions you find online. =)

Comment: A new file in `/etc/profile.d` is one reasonable place to put things like this, yes.